# Como configurar uma div de dimensão dinâmica delimitada por outras div's?

Tags: html, css

Procuro uma forma de dispor de um layout que atenda ao comportamento abaixo:

[image: Layout Proposto]

A grande questão aqui é fazer com que a div central se delimite às extremidades das demais div's, de forma que estas não se sobreponham àquela.

Fazendo uma alusão ao mundo Desktop, gostaria de adicionar uma classe CSS à minha `<div>` que simule o comportamento [`DockStyle.Fill`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle(v=vs.110).aspx).

Há como fazer isso apenas com CSS?

Comment: Coloque um max-height na div central, pra que ocupe no máximo o espaço entre as duas divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar `flexbox`

```css
body, html {
  position: relative;
  display: flex; /* repare aqui */
  flex-direction: column; /* repare aqui */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header, footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  z-index: 2;
}

section {
  flex: 1; /* repare aqui - vai ocupar todo o espaço livre no elemento pai, neste caso o body */
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  z-index: 1;
}

#placebo {
  height: 5000px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section>
  <div id="placebo"></div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Procurava algo mais nesta linha, sem que a tag de conteúdo tivesse que se preocupar com o tamanho das demais extremidades.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como funciona o comportamento do `DockStyle.Fill`, mas você poderia fazer algo desse tipo:

HTML:

```
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='content'></div>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
#header{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
#content{
 position: fixed;
 top: 100px;
 bottom: 100px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: gray;
}
#footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-color: blue;
}
```

Veja aqui no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4n0txxp/)

Answer (score 1):

Semelhante a ideia já postada há esse modo:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
header, footer{
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
}
header{  top: 0;}
footer{  bottom: 0;}

#content{
  background: gold;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="content"></div>
<footer></footer>
```

Você atribui ao `header` e ao `footer` um `height` desejado, essa alturas serão usadas mais a frente para se especificar os espaçamento da `div#content` para que ela ocupe o espaço restante.

Feito isto, basta atribuir a ambos um `position: fixed`, e `bottom` e `top`.

Com a `div#content` tendo um `position: absolute` você não necessita especificar o `height` e sim o `top` e `bottom`, sendo estes a altura do `header` e do `footer`, respectivamente. Assim o `height` desta `div` será automático. Caso queira um conteúdo com barra de rolagem, basta dar um `overflow: auto`.

### [Demo - JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sjs8esr/3/)